# Magento: Joining left table in grid

Tags: magento, join, collections

I am trying to add a grid in which I need to do a left join.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/user_collection')->join("school/school",'ref_id = referer_id',"school_name",**"left"**);
    var_dump((string)$collection->getSelect());

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Even though I have defined "left" when I see the dump it shows:

SELECT `main_table`.*, `school/school`.`school_name` FROM `admin_user` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `school` AS `school/school` ON ref_id = referer_id

I tried to do a 
         `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/user_collection')->**joinLeft**("school/school",'ref_id = referer_id',"school_name","left");` 
but for which my system does not show me any var_dump  hangs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `getSelect()` before the `join`

Comment: Did try it but the query now become SELECT `main_table`.*, `school/school`.`school_name` FROM `admin_user` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `school/school` ON ref_id = referer_id. This is not valid sql query

Comment: OK... doing this $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/user_collection')->getSelect()->joinLeft("school",'ref_id = referer_id',"school_name"); worked.

Answer (score 0):

with product collection if you want to place OR condition bw the attributes

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
      array('attribute'=>'my_attribute', 'eq'=>'0'),
      array('attribute'=>'my_other_attribute', 'neq'=>'0')
    ),
    '',
    'left'
  );
```